# react native with android virtual machine start expo project, error display java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: android, reactjs, expo, virtual-machine, native

react native with android virtual machine start expo project, error display java.net.UnknownHostException,I used npx expo start --tunnel to start the expo go program, but it keeps reporting errors on the Android VM." no address assicuated with hostname"

The project can be scanned on the phone to run, but can not be used to open the Android virtual machine, I am the first contact expo project, do not know how to solve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.